# How to fit 6 photos on a slideshow instead of 5?

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

The following code is a slideshow page with 5 slideshows using Owl Slideshow Platform. Each of these slideshows show five pictures each at a time. I need six photos on one slideshow shown at one time instead of five. I have tried experimenting with the <!--Slideshow Headline section--!>. I tried commenting and seeing what would happen if I changed values, however, no luck. My question is how do a make one of the slideshows show six pictures at a time instead of five? Thank you.

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://use.typekit.net/oov2wcw.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Fsdadasdsadet</title>
    <link href="/FreeCAD/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <script>
       /* When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */
    var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function() {
     var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
     if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
       document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
     } else {
       document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-3000px";
     }
     prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Century Gothic;">
    <div id="navbar" style="background-color:#ffffff;text-align: center;">
        <a href="isdasex.html"><img alt="Insadsdam" id="border" src="/Index%20Files/indsf.png" style="width:75px;height:75px;"></a> 
        <a href="frdasad.html"><img alt="Freesdasadt" id="borderwo" src="/Index%20Files/fredsfd.png" style="width:75px;height:75px;"></a> 
        <a href="yasdeen.html"><img alt="Ysaden" id="border" src="/Index%20Files/yadsf.png" style="width:75px;height:75px;"></a> 
        <a href="ansdaemy.html"><img alt="AnssaAAemy" id="border" src="/Index%20Files/ansdfsr.png" style="width:75px;height:75px;"></a> 
        <a href="endsatsdent.html"><img alt="Aasdon" id="border" src="/Index%20Files/amdfn.jpg" style="width:75px;height:75px;"></a> 
        <a href="hudsas.html"><img alt="Hsad" id="border" src="/Index%20Files/hufdss.jpg" style="width:75px;height:75px;"></a> 
        <a href="cisdaign.html"><img alt="citdasgn" id="border" src="/Index%20Files/citdsfgn.jpg" style="width:75px;height:75px;"></a> 
        <a href="osdar.html"><img alt="other" id="border" src="/Index%20Files/odsfer.jpg" style="width:75px;height:75px;"></a>
    </div>
    <img src="/FresdD/logo.png" width="200" height="40" alt="FasdAD" class="center">

    <h3>Frsaddsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss.</h3>
    <h3><a href="https://www.w3schools.com"> Source Code</a></h3>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script> 
    
    
    <!--Center Logo-->
    <style>
        /* Logo */
        .center {
          display: block;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
        }
        
    </style>

    <!--Scrollbar-->
    <style>
        /* width */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
         width: 20px;
       }
       
       /* Track */
       ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
         box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
         border-radius: 0px;
       }
        
       /* Handle */
       ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
         background: lightgrey; 
         border-radius: 5px;
       }
       
       /* Handle on hover */
       ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
         background: red; 
       }
  </style>

    <!--Slideshow Headline-->
    <style>
    /* Image padding on left */
    #slider .container-fluid{
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    }
    /* Image padding on bottom */
    #slider .slider-inner{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px
    }
    
    .slider-inner .item img{
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    /* Make circle */
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    }
    .slider-inner h1{
    color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;

    }
    </style>

    <!--Slideshow-->
    <script>
       $(function () {
           var count = 0;
           $('.owl-carousel').each(function () {
               $(this).attr('id', 'owl-demo' + count);
               $('#owl-demo' + count).owlCarousel({
                   navigation: true,
                   slideSpeed: 200,
                   pagination: false,
                   singleItem: false,
                   autoPlay: 2000,
              

               });
               count++;
           });
       });
    </script> 


    <!--Slideshow-->
    <section id="slider">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="slider-inner">
                <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="owl-demo" >
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/Fsdasd/ppf/person/l1.jpg"><h3><b>fhgh</b></h3><h3>Basdsdar</h3></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/Fsdasd/ppf/person/b1.jpg"><h3><b>isdadssd</b></h3><h3>sdes</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/Fsdasd/ppf/person/b2.jpg"><h3><b>rdsad</b></h3><h3>Basdes</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/Fsdasd/ppf/person/b3.jpg"><h3><b>nsade</b></h3><h3>Basd</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/Fsdasd/ppf/person/b4.jpg"><h3><b>yesdan</b></h3><h3>asdses</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/Fsdasd/ppf/person/b5.jpg"><h3><b>ssdasd</b></h3><h3>dsaNoses</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-inner ">
                <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="owl-demo" >
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/sdasd/ppf/person/l2.jpg"><h3 ><b>sdds</b></h3><h3>sdar</h3></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/sdasd/ppf/person/t1.jpg"><h3 ><b>sddsbdasdaah</b></h3><h3>asd</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/sdasd/ppf/person/t2.jpg"><h3 ><b>sddsdur</b></h3><h3>sda</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/sdasd/ppf/person/t3.jpg"><h3 ><b>sddsdndari</b></h3><h3>sdo</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/sdasd/ppf/person/t4.jpg"><h3 ><b>sddstton</b></h3><h3>Tsdao</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-inner ">
                <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="owl-demo" >
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/saddsd/ppf/person/l3.jpg"><h3><b>Asddsman</b></h3><h3>Csddader</h3></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/saddsd/ppf/person/c1.jpg"><h3><b>Asddsdsan</b></h3><h3>Cesad</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/saddsd/ppf/person/c2.jpg"><h3><b>Jsddsynh</b></h3><h3>Csd</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/saddsd/ppf/person/c3.jpg"><h3><b>Msddslem</b></h3><h3>Cadss</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/saddsd/ppf/person/c4.jpg"><h3><b>RsddsCarsdo</b></h3><h3>Ceasd</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/saddsd/ppf/person/c5.jpg"><h3><b>Tsdds Tran</b></h3><h3>Cerasdrus</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-inner">
                <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="owl-demo" >
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/sdaasd/ppf/person/l4.jpg"><h3><b>JsddsMcDdsld</b></h3><h3>Nucasder</h3></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/sdaasd/ppf/person/n1.jpg"><h3><b>wddsw</b></h3><h3>dsar Node</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/sdaasd/ppf/person/n2.jpg"><h3><b>wsddsHsdda</b></h3><h3>sdaode</h3><h4>Duties: Casd1</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/sdaasd/ppf/person/n3.jpg"><h3><b>wsddsim</b></h3><h3>asdode</h3><h4>Dutiesdsasd</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/sdaasd/ppf/person/n4.jpg"><h3><b>sdasddsSage) Han</b></h3><h3>NuasdNode</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/sdaasd/ppf/person/n5.jpg"><h3><b>dsasddsho</b></h3><h3>asd Node</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-inner ">
                <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="owl-demo">
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/sadsd/ppf/person/l5.jpg"><h3><b>dssddscott</b></h3><h3>ewusdaon Leader</h3></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/sadsd/ppf/person/p1.jpg"><h3><b>dssdddsung</b></h3><h3>Ndastion</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/sadsd/ppf/person/p2.jpg"><h3><b>sasddsane</b></h3><h3>Nullsadtion</h3><h4>Dutiesaddsmber</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/sadsd/ppf/person/p3.jpg"><h3><b>sddsksdh</b></h3><h3>Nusddaiasds:</h4></div>
                    <div class="item"><img alt="p" src="/sadsd/ppf/person/p4.jpg"><h3><b>sssddya</b></h3><h3>Nullasdon</h3><h4>Duties:</h4></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by adding the `items` option when initializing the carousel. I've tested it on CodePen, and it seems to work. I've tried with different numbers.

```
$('#owl-demo' + count).owlCarousel({
  items: 6,
  ...
});
```

You should consider using the latest version of [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/). Here is the documentation for the available options [Documentation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html). On this version it will work for sure, just by changing the `items` value.